# 4 phased led brightness for a rotating impression

Tags: led, analog

I am making a desk's lighthouse that will have its light revolving 360 degrees, hopefully using minimal circuitry.

For this, I intend to use 4 LED lights that would have each pulsating at a different phase of highest voltage going from 100% to 0% in 90 "degrees" differences.

For example, at time

```
        LED1,  LED2,  LED3,  LED4
00.0sec: 100%, 0%,    0%,    0%
01.0sec: 66%,  33%,   0%,    0%
01.5sec: 50%,  50%,   0%,    0%
03.0sec: 0%,   100%,  0%,    0%
04.5sec: 0%,   50%,   50%,   0%
06.0sec: 0%,   0%,    100%,  0%
07.5sec: 0%,   0%,    50%,   50%
09.0sec: 0%,   0%,    0%,    100%
10.5sec: 50%,  0%,    0%,    50%
12.0sec: 100%, 0%,    0%,    0%
```

I could easily use a ATtiny45 with a programmed loop on each pin, but is there any simple way to use it with only analog circuitry? I imagine capacitors, resistors and transistors would be required but I honestly have no idea on how to get even a single pulsating led without the use of programming, let alone 4 in phase.

If not feasible, I'd like to read your ideas on how to give a rotating lighthouse feel with a chip. I'm currently working on a loop of 64 values going from 0 to 15 that will affect 4 different PWM duty cycle with a +0, +16, +32 and +48 increment. It is more granular than what I would wish but I hope it will look natural.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You won't get more minimal circuitry than the microcontroller solution (1 chip).

Comment: analog circuit only makes it off topic here ... this site is for arduino questions

Comment: Thanks for letting me know for the impression of off topic, I was going under the assumption with the questions here asked that this would be the best stack exchange site for analog circuitry

Comment: As @Mat says. With discrete components even without PWM it is not worth it. MCU is simpler, takes less space and even most likely cheaper. So I'd suggest you to edit your question to focus on this part.

Comment: An analog solution could be a [ring oscillator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVCW2A0C68A), but honestly just use a micro

Comment: You could use addressable LEDs so you would need only 1 MCU pin to control as many LEDs as you want (and also simplify your wiring).